# Any risks using Macports?

Tags: macos, unix, development-environment, macports

I'm considering installing MacPorts on my Mac so I can have easy access to *nix dev tools/apps.  However, I'm wondering if there are any risks.  I'm OK with the inevitable compatibility issue from time to time (hear Snow Leopard + MacPorts has issues) but I do not want the stability of my "core" Mac system to be affected.  I'm also curious if MacPorts adds any significant security risks.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MacPorts uses a totally different directory for its installs — /opt/local — than any normal program. I've never seen it affect the stability of a system (I'm not even sure how it would), and I've had it installed on many computers for several years.

Comment: @Chuck re "how it would", we have stories involving rsync and tar installed by MacPorts as dependencies in the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 4):

I use Darvin/MacPorts for years now. I use them extensively. Abut once a year after a significant update ports break in a way that it is easier to delete them and start anew. So that is exactly what I do. I figure that spending 2-3 hours reinstalling them is good investment considering how much time ports save handling all open source software for me. Removing ports is not a trivial tasks though unless you use this command:

```
sudo rm -rf \
/opt/local \
/Applications/MacPorts \
/Applications/DarwinPorts \
/Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
/Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.\* \
/Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
/Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
/Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg
```

Comment: Gah! Four years using fink (heavily!) and never had something like this happen. Come over the the side of all that is good and holy.

Comment: It is a matter of preference. I used fink as well, but decided on ports at the end.

Comment: I feel like Fink is messier than MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts can play some funny games with your path variable, taking precedence over installed system programs that should have precedence. Stuff like python and ruby becomes kind of a mess, if there's anything that depends on some specific version. It's not typically permanent damage though. Most problems can be resolved by uninstalling macports, and reverting the path env variable.

Comment: It's quite straightforward. MacPorts installs *nearly* everything in /opt/local/ (see elsewhere for exceptions) and modifies your shell .profile to insert /opt/local/bin at the front of $PATH.  The intent is to ensure that, by default, user commands installed by the various MacPorts packages get executed in preference to any Apple-supplied commands with the same name.  Often that is what you want.  If not, you can modify your $PATH or use an absolute path to the version you want. Be aware of the differences, though: I've been burned by an implicitly installed MacPorts rsync, for example.

Comment: @Ned As you say, there's nothing to worry about *as long as you remember that MacPorts installs utilities with the same name as the system ones*. The trick is the first time it happens to you though. See my own story, and thanks for warning about rsync, I'll pay attention when I use it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [rather long] list of tools included with the Xcode IDE?  As of Snow Leopard, it includes gcc 4.0, 4,2, llvm-gcc, and Clang, for example.

When you do the installation of Xcode, there is an optional install that will populate many of the standard unix-y dev tools into /usr/bin/, etc... They are normally found in /Developer/bin/ since Xcode started to support the ability to move the dev tools.

Personally, I have a long background of Unix development, including cross-platform work, and had been an avid Fink, then MacPorts, user for years.  When doing a clean install of Leopard, I never got around to installing Fink/MacPorts and haven't had a need to since.

Both MacPorts and Fink are awesome.  If you do need various Unix-y goop, either one will do nicely.   However, I just wanted to make sure you were aware of the fullness of Unix-y development potential that ships with Mac OS X.

(Sticking with the system tools provides a few additional advantages;  your code is more accessible to others and the dev tools have been optimized / patched / fixed for optimum support of Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

Its fine - I use MacPorts - it won't overwrite any of your existing apps in the Path.  I've been using it for years.  However, I did completely break my Mac Ports install - I now can't install or selfupdate.  But its only stopped me from installing any new ports - it hasn't effected the stability of any existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the current situation regarding this, but in the past, I have been burned in the following scenario:

1. Apple wants to make life easy and provide compatibility to ex-Mac OS users, modifies the system version of tar to encode data forks or some other Mac-specific metadata in tar files. They consider, rightly, that it's "just another filesystem". The encoding is nothing fancy (similar to the encoding used for FAT32 filesystems) but it's a nice touch.
2. MacPorts want to control the version of tar used when doing MacPorts-related things (perhaps fix a bug that has been present in some system-provided version), installs pristine GNU tar as a dependency for some package.
3. MacPorts tar is first in $PATH, is used in a place where Apple tar behavior was desired.
4. Backup is revealed to be worthless.

I am still using MacPorts though. I just pay attention at the time of using tar. MacPorts is such a big timesaver that I couldn't do without it.